# Windows 7 Hidden Process with Network Traffic

Tags: windows-7, network-traffic

This is about Windows 7, but I am not an expert on the operating system.

Someone I know recently got a brand new (less than 2 days old never used before) laptop with Windows 7.  I was asked to make sure it wasn't making a bunch of connections to random internet servers.

I fired up wireshark and immediately noticed a bunch of traffic on "204.79.197.223".  So I ran "netstat -bov" on the command line and found the process ID associated with that IP address.  So I checked task manager and the task was not listed.  So I ran sysinternals "process explorer" to find the process, but it wasn't listed there.  So I checked netstat again and saw that they had switched to a new IP (13.107.4.50) and a new process ID.  So I checked and yes it was again a process hidden from task manager, and "process explorer" could display it.  SysInternals didn't seem to have anything useful to tell me about the process, just that it's name was "svchost.exe", same as what netstat reported.

WireShark reported these connections as taking over 150 MB of network traffic in the brief time I was monitoring.  By reverse DNS lookup, both of the IP addresses belong to microsoft.

How can I figure out what this hidden process is?   How can I stop it?  How can I stop it from coming back?  Thanks.  I hate windows stealing bandwidth.  Since the computer isn't mine, I'm trying to avoid anything too drastic.

By the time I finished writing this, the second process is over 308 MB of internet traffic to/from microsoft in 44 minutes (as reported by wireshark).

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Updates?

It's probably windows updates, if the system is that new.

If you are that concerned switch to Linux something that doesn't update without your permission.

I think windows 7 has some control still that allows you to stop windows from updating it isn't as smart as the newer versions of NT so if it says it's off it should be but...
Microsoft can ignore your preferences if there are other systems in place still. So after you change your settings to `never update` check to make sure it's stopped perhaps after reboot (Because registry?)

## Windows Defender?

Make sure window's defender is stopped it dosen't work on anything new and uses way too many resources this could also be the problem.

### Hacks

There is a way to break windows update so that it never works properly but getting it back up and running is painful.

If you move to windows 10 there is "*No way to turn off updates*" but if you set don't use metered connections to update and set all of your networks as metered then it *shouldn't* update...

Comment: Switching to Linux is not an option.  I hate microsoft enough to switch to commodore 64 if it would work.  I'll try disabling windows updates later.

Comment: Btw venerable : "ven·er·a·ble , accorded a great deal of respect, especially because of age, wisdom, or character."